# Textbox Insert + Update Different Tabel in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Question : How do I insert & Update into different tables using `TextBox` In `CodeIgniter`

My database structure

**t_mynetpoin**

```
|id_mynetpoin |tot_poin |last_modified| nim |
```

**t_log_mynetpoin**

```
|id_log_mynetpoin | id_paket_redeem | id_mynetpoin | status | total | time | keterangan |
```

**My Model**

```
public function get($tabel='',$where='',$order='',$limit='',$from=''){
if (!empty($where)) $this->db->where($where);
if (!empty($order)) $this->db->order_by($order);

$query = $this->db->get($tabel,$limit,$from);

if ($query){
  return $query->result();
}
else {
  return array();
}

public function insert($tabel,$data){
    $query = $this->db->insert($tabel,$data);
    if($query) return 1;
    else return 0;
    }

public function update($tabel,$where,$data){
   $this->db->where($where);
   $query = $this->db->update($tabel,$data);
    if ($query) {
     return 1;
    }else{
     return 0 ;
    }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
public function do_edit($id){
    $post = $this->input->post(NULL, FALSE);
    $now = date('Y-m-d');
    $post['last_modified'] = $now;

    $query = $this->Super_Model->update('t_mynetpoin','id_mynetpoin = '.$id,$post);
    $idpr = "2";
    $sts= "tambah";
    $total = $post['tot_poin'];
    $post_tot['total'] = $total;

    $ket = $post['keterangan'];
    $post_ket['keterangan'] = $ket;

    $this->Super_Model->query('INSERT INTO t_log_mynetpoin (id_paket_redeem, id_mynet_poin, status, total, keterangan) VALUES ($idpr,$id,$sts,$post_tot,$post_ket);');
    if($query==1){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User berhasil di edit!');
        redirect("super_admin/User");
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User gagal di edit!');
        redirect("super_admin/User/add");
    }
}
```

**Part My View**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url("$url")?>">
    <p>Masukan Poin yang akan di tambah</p>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;"><?php echo form_dropdown("nim", $ambil_nim,@$nim, 'class="form-control" id="nim" disabled="disabled"'); ?></div>
    <div><input class="form-control col-sm-10" name = "tot_poin" type="text" value = "<?php echo $tpn?>" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"/></div>
    <div><textarea class="form-control col-sm-10" name="keterangan" placeholder="Keterangan menambahkan poin" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;height: 100px;"></textarea></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer" style="margin-top: 150px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Submit</button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

**Error**

[Error Img Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vMA1.png)

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'keterangan' in 'field list'

UPDATE `t_mynetpoin` SET `tot_poin` = '8000', `keterangan` = 'hv', `last_modified` = '2016-05-25' WHERE `id_mynetpoin` = 1

Filename: E:/xampp/htdocs/mynet/application/models/Super_Model.php

Line Number: 64
```

Comment: Hi irfanhans, could you paste your error as formatted text instead of image? this would be useful if anybody else get the same.

Comment: i have copy an error code

Comment: It looks like your database doesn't know `keterangan` column. Indeed, table t_mynetpoin only has the columns you said: `|id_mynetpoin |tot_poin |last_modified| nim |` ...

Comment: You are updating table `t_mynetpoin` which has no column named `keterangan`

Comment: column `keterangan` available in t_log_mynetpoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `$data`should be different depending on which table you want to modify.

Here what's looking odd:

```
$query = $this->Super_Model->update('t_mynetpoin','id_mynetpoin = '.$id,$post);
```

You must construct `$data` from the `$post` data instead of giving the raw `$post` to your update method.

Or in case you're not updating the right table -- `t_mynetpoin` instead of **`t_log_mynetpoin`**, you could try:

```
  $query = $this->Super_Model->update('t_log_mynetpoin','id_mynetpoin = '.$id,$post);
```

### alternate solution:

Consider writing complete query in both cases:

```
$query = $this->Super_Model->update('t_mynetpoin','id_mynetpoin = '.$id,$post);
```

Thusly becomes:

```
$this->Super_Model->query('UPDATE t_mynetpoin SET tot_poin = $idpr,...
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer XD , i use array to fix...

**My Controller Edited**

```
public function do_edit($id){
    $post = $this->input->post(NULL, FALSE);

    $id_paket_redeem = "2"; 
    $status = "Tambah"; 
    $log = array(
        "id_paket_redeem"=>$id_paket_redeem,
        "id_mynet_poin"=>$id,
        "status"=>$status,
        "total"=>$post['tot_poin'],
        "keterangan"=>$post['keterangan']
    );

    $this->Super_Model->insert('t_log_mynetpoin',$log);


    $now = date('Y-m-d');
    $post['last_modified'] = $now;

    $up = array(
        "tot_poin"=>$post['tot_poin'],
        "last_modified"=>$post['last_modified']
    );
    $query = $this->Super_Model->update('t_mynetpoin','id_mynetpoin = '.$id,$up);

    if($query==1){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User berhasil di edit!');
        redirect("super_admin/Coin");
    }else{
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User gagal di edit!');
        redirect("super_admin/Coin");
    }
}
```